# Unity add a listener form dictionary to a TextMeshProUGUI Text?

Tags: c#, dictionary, unity-game-engine, listener, textmeshpro

I am making a project with Unity that using RestSharp API's.

I can specify and retrieve language keys and values ​​from the server without any problems, and I can keep these values ​​up to date in a dictionary and listen. As soon as the values ​​arrive, that is, when the dictionary is updated, when I want to send the data to the texts, only the active ones in the hierarchy are updated.

```
public void SetTexts()
{
    var languageTexts = FindObjectsOfType<LanguageKeys>();
    foreach (LanguageKeys languageText in languageTexts)
    {
        languageText.SetTexts();
    }
}
```

When I send the values ​​with these codes, they are written instead of the values ​​without any problems.

It also happens if I want to rerun the SetText() function with the OnEnable function, but when the values ​​are coming from the server, I get an error because the key values ​​in the Dictionary are null.

Is there a function like UnityEvent, Action<> where TextMeshProUGUI text can listen to the values ​​from the dictionary and update itself when the values ​​change? How can I improve the code so that it is a more optimized system?

Answer (score 0):

[`FindObjectsOfType`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.FindObjectsOfType.html) by default only returns **active** and **enabled** instances!

In newer Unity versions (2020.3) there is the optional parameter `bool includeInactive` so in order to include also the inactive ones you want to use

```
var languageTexts = FindObjectsOfType<LanguageKeys>(true);
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I thought of that too. I'm working on version 2020.3.24f1 I didn't know it supported this feature just